# ¿Significan lo mismo "sí mismo" y "uno mismo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, pronombres, reflexivos

Paseando por un centro comercial hoy me he encontrado con la siguiente frase motivacional:

> La confianza en sí mismo es el primer secreto del éxito.

La verdad es que la frase me sonó un poco extraña, dado que tal y como estaba redactada parecía que quien escribió la frase no trataba de referirse ni a él a mí como quienes debíamos tener confianza, sino a una tercera persona (a fin de cuentas, [*sí* es la forma tónica de *él*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XmOP8Ia)). Yo habría más bien dicho:

> La confianza en uno mismo es el primer secreto del éxito.

Así tanto el que escribió la frase como yo mismo estaríamos incluidos en ella. Pero ¿es esto así? ¿Cómo entendéis vosotros la frase tal y como la vi escrita? ¿Significan lo mismo las dos propuestas o le veis diferencias?

<sub>Nota: es posible que la frase original sea el resultado de una traducción hecha a la ligera, no me fijé en quién la escribió.</sub>

Comment: Creo que lo que pasa es que se está expresando una idea completa, basada en "self-confidence," y muchas veces la persona no se detiene a pensar, nomás se avienta a decir "confianza en sí mismo" en qualquier situatión.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según la RAE, no es incorrecto pero sí desaconsejable el uso del "sí" impersonal o genérico:

> No es recomendable emplear el reflexivo *sí* en oraciones impersonales con referente inespecífico o genérico; en esos casos, lo normal y preferible es usar el indefinido *uno*; así, en lugar de *Aquí se viene a hablar de sí mismo* resulta preferible decir *Aquí se viene a hablar de uno mismo*.

He [aquí](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=OPRQrNgR6D6MJDLkBh) la fuente.